# Vlookup on ID and Date (Fuzzy on Date) Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to essentially do a Vlookup on two columns ID (where I want the match to be exact) and a date field (where I want it to be fuzzy).

Suppose you have a table in "Sheet1" about hospital admissions like so:

```
ID  Admit_Date
000 01/01/2016
000 06/01/2016
001 02/01/2016
002 04/01/2016
```

Then I have another table in "Sheet2" about followup care like so:

```
ID  Followup_Date
000 01/05/2016
000 06/06/2016
001 02/02/2016
002 04/04/2016
```

In sheet 1 I want to return the corresponding `Followup_Date` which is the closest Date After the `Admit_Date`

So my final result will look something like

```
ID  Admit_Date   Followup_Date
000 01/01/2016   01/05/2016
000 06/01/2016   06/06/2016
001 02/01/2016   02/02/2016
002 04/01/2016   04/04/2016
```

What's the best way to do this using a formula in Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0):

### **Update**

*Get " Followup_Date", formula on Sheet1*

You could use this formula:
`=QUERY(SORT(FILTER(sheet2!B:B,sheet2!A:A=A2,sheet2!B:B>=B2)),"limit 1")`

---

### **Original (wrong) answer**

*Get "Admit_Date", formula on Sheet2*

try this formula:

`=VLOOKUP(B2,(FILTER(sheet1!B:B,sheet1!A:A=A2)),1)`

you'll need to paste it in cell C2 and copy it down.

This formula is doing:

1. [filtering data](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en), doing exact match `sheet1!A:A=A2`
2. doind [vlookup](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en), with default parameter, that gives the closest Date After the `Admit_Date`. This will work with numbers, and date is serial number in spreadsheets, so this will fit you.

---

If you like big ArrayFormulas, here's one, that you don't need to drag down, it'll expand automatically:

```
=ArrayFormula(RIGHT(VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(OFFSET(A1,1,,counta(A2:A)),{UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),row(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A)))*100000},2,0)+OFFSET(B1,1,,counta(A2:A)),VLOOKUP(OFFSET(sheet1!A1,1,,counta(sheet1!A2:A)),{UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),row(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A)))*100000},2,0)+OFFSET(sheet1!B1,1,,counta(sheet1!A2:A)),1),5)*1)
```

Comment: In your first answer, should sheet1 be sheet2?

Comment: Also the Vlookup with the default parameter is not giving me the closest Date after the `Admit_Date`. Instead I'm getting an error that the Vlookup cannot find the value.

Comment: In particular, the problem is that `Followup_Date` is always greater than or equal to `Admit_Date` but the default parameter gives the closest day before `Admit_Date` so the `VLOOKUP` fails. I'm hesitant to try the ArrayFormula since the `VLOOKUP` and `FILTER` method looks way more readable.

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood you. I've made update with use of simple formula. Sure there's also ArrayFormula solution. I'll make you know if I find one.